# Update Datatable with another

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have 2 C# datatables, the master(datatable1) that I want too update has many rows but the second contains only a few unique rows. Below is what I am trying to achieve.[image]

I have searched to find a way to do this with loops and LINQ but none seem to  update the ECAD column.

I tried this.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dtARIAA.Rows)
{
      foreach (DataRow row1 in dtReport.Rows)
      {
            if (row["Ser"] == row1["Ser"] )
            {
                row1["ECAD"] = row["Date"];
            }
      }
}
dtReport.AcceptChanges();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell from your schema above you just need to write and execute this SQL.

`Table1` is you table with dates to update, Table2 is your second table with dates

```
update t1 set t1.ECAD  = [t2].[Date] from Table1 t1 
                         inner join Table2 t2  ON t2.Ser = t1.Ser
```

But if you want to work with two DataTables already in memory then you could use

```
// Loop over the table with the unique Ser value and with the date to transfer
foreach (DataRow r in dtARIAA.Rows)
{
      // Get the rows in the destination table with the same "Ser" value
      DataRow[] destRows = dtReport.Select("Ser = " + r["Ser"]);

      // Now update the destination table rows with the Date value
      foreach (DataRow row1 in destRows)
          row1["ECAD"] = r["Date"];
}
dtReport.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks, I can do it in SQL but I need to do it in C# with datatables.